# ICO - question regarding private network

Tags: private-blockchain, ico, crowdsale

my team and I have been working on developing an application, based on a private ethereum network, due to the high gas cost of our contracts on the main chain.

Now we would like to proceed to the next stage and start an ICO and our idea was to use the main network during the crowd sale to generate our tokens. And then move these to the private network. What would be the best possible way/pattern to do so in a safe, transparent manner?

Comment: why you need to move your contract to private network after ICO ?

Comment: reason being is that the gas fees are so expensive that it makes more financial sense to provide servers. We are expecting to have 10k+ contract executions a day and this is a rather conservative estimate.

Comment: Since you are in control of the private network one solution is to create a 2-way peg with mainnet, so you can exchange tokens between them.

Comment: thank you very much and we appreciate it. Do you have any good sources regarding this technology? Also please send me an eth address, so we can provide some thank you!

Comment: @berlinguyinca There's a nice explantion from ConsenSys between Bitcoin and Ethereum https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/taking-stock-bitcoin-and-ethereum-4382f0a2f17. Since you have to do something similar between two Ethereum blockchains it should be easier.